# Grunt css:min task don't exec

Tags: css, gruntjs, less, minify

Let me explain...

I've bought a theme (not me, but it's complicated). This theme gave me a LESS files. Then, i think to myself: "Oh yeah, i'll compile all the LESS files and minify with Grunt".

Right after run grunt task, the problem shows your face:

```
Warning: property missing ':' near line 1035:28
```

The terminal don't show where is this line "1035", but i think it's on the main css file (the generated before minify). But, there's nothing wrong with the line 1035.

Line 1035:

```
color: #ff3b30 /*{fcError}*/;
```

Just for knowledge: This is the exactly way what i do with my own LESS files. This error just appear with this LESS files.
Okay, maybe the problem is the CSS written by the author, but, the minify version came from the normal version (css without min). In other words:

LESS -> CSS (not minified) :: OK

CSS (not minified) -> CSS (minified) :: NOT OKAY

Then, the problem isn't with LESS, it's on the generated CSS?

Comment: Hmm, looks like a bug in the minifier? (I see nothing wrong with this CSS line too). Try to process the same piece of CSS with the standalone version of the same minifier maybe just to make sure...

Comment: your error is possible related to: https://github.com/reworkcss/css/issues/24